# Unwanted space creeping between views - Views dont render in rectangular edges

Tags: android, android-xml

I have the following layout: [image]

Here is my List code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my list_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#D81902">

    </View>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/view"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="20dip"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_calendar_list" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView31"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="#f1f1f1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the theme I use with the parent activity of this Fragment:

```
  <style name="LoaderTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    </style>
```

I want the view with id: `android:id="@+id/view"` to be a continious line from top to bottom, however I am not sure why the edges are rendered oval instead of square/ rectangular? What options do I have here?

Comment: try giving some minor padding say `1dp` to your relative layout in list_row.xml and as your relative layout is having fixed height why not give this view fixed height also

Comment: Actually it was my mistake, I did not research properly. I was setting a background drawable to the view - which in fact was oval. Now I changed it to simple colors and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the divider from the listview..

Set in your xml:

```
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```

Comment: Yes matey, I have already done that. The fact being that the vertical line working properly in one of my other apps. I think RelativeLayout is playing a spoil sport here.